# Send xml content over Soap

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, asmx

I am sending a soap Request that looks like the following :

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:55056/myWebService.asmx");
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
httpRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/myWebMethod");
httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
//Create Stream and Complete Request             
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);
soapRequest.Append("<soap:Body>");
soapRequest.Append("<myWebMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">");
soapRequest.Append("<eventType>myEventType</eventType>");
soapRequest.Append("<eventId><firstNode>myProduct</firstNode></eventId>");
soapRequest.Append("<eventData>myEventData</eventData>");
soapRequest.Append("</myWebMethod>");
soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body>");
streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
streamWriter.Close();
//Get the Response    
HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
```

My problem is that eventId contains some xml content =>  <firstNode>myProduct </firstNode>, and when I send the **soapRequest**, on the other side am getting in debug mode: eventType="myEventType" eventId="" eventData=null

My web method looks like

```
        [WebMethod]
        public void myWebMethod(string eventType, string eventId, string eventData)
        {
        }
```

What Can i do to make my webmethod accept this small "xml":

```
<firstNode>myProduct</firstNode>
```

**Edit1:**

Thank you for your replay MarxWright, i've tried this, but its not working. I managed to convert manually your sMessage by replacing  : "<" with "& lt;" and ">" with "& gt;" It worked.But it would be nice if i can rather make changes on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work but you could try to use the following function which will convert the message for sending, I believe you might be then able to read the data at the other end.

```
String sMessage = "<tag>Data</tag>";

String messageFilling = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(sMessage);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your response could you explain it a little further. If the message is reaching the other end and you need to make change could you not covert it back into an Xml document again using the contents of the message?